# React save global state before page refresh

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, react-state

I'm using React to build an website where the user needs to login.
The website keeps states from the user.
[image]

This is the state of auth.
This state isn't changed much.
When I refresh the page my state gets refreshed too!
I want to keep the state if someone refreshes the page.

I looked at: https://hackernoon.com/how-to-take-advantage-of-local-storage-in-your-react-projects-a895f2b2d3f2 but that is only for states in current page only.
I want to save the main state of the app no matter on what page the user is on when page is refreshed.
**How to do that?**

I don't know what code you guys need, so ask me and Ill add it to the question.
I really need help with this.

Comment: so are you application multi-page rather single-page?

Comment: Im using multi-page so the global state exists on each page, but got lost after refresh

Answer (score 0):

You can save your state in localstorage using [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist). It will also update localstorage when redux state will be updated and persist when page reloaded

Comment: I know, but I don't know how to implement this in my code and I don't want to add those code to each page.